# Images not saving in Laravel mysql database

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, image-uploading

I am trying to upload images to my laravel project. 
There is no error that I can't find and have been trying to debug it. The images get saved to the local folder present in the project, images, but it doesn't get uploaded to the mysql database. The other fields are inserted to the database, only the image part is not getting uploaded.

This is my controller code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
      ]);


      if ($validator->passes()) {


        $input = $request->all();
        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);


        Employee::create($input);


        return response()->json(['success'=>'done']);
      }


      return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

This is how I am calling the images to get saved.

```
<?php  $no=1; ?>
            @foreach ($employees as $employee)
            <tr class="post{{$employee->id}}">
                <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->bank->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->bankbranch->location}}</td>
                <td>"{{ asset('images /'.$employee->photo)}}" width= "50px" height = "50px"</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->created_at}}</td> 
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm"  data-id="{{$employee->id}}" data-bank_id="{{$employee->bank->name}}" data-bankbranch_id="{{$employee->bankbranch->location}}" data-name="{{$employee->name}}" data-phone="{{$employee->phone}}" data-email="{{$employee->email}}" data-address="{{$employee->address}}" data-acname="{{$employee->acname}}" data-acnumber="{{$employee->acnumber}}" data-rnumber="{{$employee->rnumber}}" >
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-id="{{$employee->id}}" data-bank_id="{{$employee->bank->name}}" data-bankbranch_id="{{$employee->bankbranch->location}}" data-name="{{$employee->name}}" data-phone="{{$employee->phone}}" >
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="{{$employee->id}}" data-bank_id="{{$employee->bank->name}}" data-bankbranch_id="{{$employee->bankbranch->location}}" data-name="{{$employee->name}}" data-phone="{{$employee->phone}}" >
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

And this is the ajax call to save the images.

```
$(document).on('click','.create-modal', function() {
        $('#create').modal('show');
        $('.form-horizontal').show();
        $('.modal-title').text('Add Employee');
    });
    $('#employeeinput').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = document.forms.namedItem("employeeinput"); 
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        //var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url  = $(this).attr('action');
        var post = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajax({
            type: post,
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataTy: 'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('.error').remove();
                $('#table').append("<tr class='post" + data.id + "'>"+
                    "<td>" + data.id + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.name + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.photo  + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.bank_name + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.bankbranch_location + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.created_at + "</td>"+
                    "<td><button class='show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-bank_id='" + data.bank_name + "' data-bankbranch_id='" + data.bankbranch_location + "' data-name='" + data.name + "' data-phone='" + data.phone + "'><span class='fa fa-eye'></span></button> <button class='edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-bank_id='" + data.bank_name + "' data-bankbranch_id='" + data.bankbranch_location + "' data-name='" + data.name + "' data-phone='" + data.phone + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-bank_id='" + data.bank_name + "' data-bankbranch_id='" + data.bankbranch_location + "' data-name='" + data.name + "' data-phone='" + data.phone + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></td>"+
                    "</tr>");
            }
        });
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#phone').val('');
    })
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide us how "Employee" class looks like ? and how you want to store image on database ? Is just public path ? base64 encoded image ?